# I can't move my gun

Tags: mesh

hi i need help i don't know what he gave i tried everything and nothing works.How can i move the gun in my hands? when i move my hand so the gun doesn't move with my hand why? i looked at various tutorials and nothing works just i don't know

[image]

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Comment: check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXCq8CncEeA and @DuarteFarrajotaRamos rooooh, it's kinda sweet :)

Comment: thanks = wilks but there is another problem = when moving the weapon only one moves from the weapon but not the other that moves elsewhere